# Horizontal list with rounded corner background

Tags: tikz-pgf, enumerate

I would like to display the elements of a list (`enumerate`) horizontally. As I read I can achieve this by using the `inline` option. Furthermore I would like to highlight the items with a box that has a background color and rounded corners. As I understand I could achieve the highlighting with tikz. Would this be the best way to go?

Answer (score 1):

You cna use for this `tcolorbox` package with library `raster`.
Example from [manual](https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) page 282:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{raster}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=3,
size=small,colframe=red!50!black,colback=red!10!white]
\tcbitem One
\tcbitem Two
\tcbitem Three
\tcbitem Four
\end{tcbitemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\newtcbox{\mybox}{enhanced,nobeforeafter,tcbox raise base,boxrule=0.4pt,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,
  right=0mm,left=0mm,arc=1pt,boxsep=2pt,before upper={\vphantom{dlg}},
  colframe=green!50!black,coltext=green!25!black,colback=green!10!white,
}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
            \node[shape=circle,fill=green!10!white,draw=green!50!black,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate*}[label=\protect\circled{\arabic*}]
    \item \mybox{xxx}
    \item \mybox{dsxxxxg}
    \item \mybox{xx}
\end{enumerate*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's a good starting point. But I found now way to dynamically adjust the size of the boxes to the content. Is this possible?